# Retrieving DNA sequences from a database of protein sequences?

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta, genome, protein-database

I have 1000's of protein sequences in FASTA and their accession numbers. I want to go back into the whole genome shotgun database and retrieve all DNA sequences that encode for a protein identical to one in my list of initial sequences.

I've tried running a tBlastn with <10 results for each sequence, 1 per query and e-value below 1e-100 or with an e-value of zero and I'm not getting any results. I would like to automate this entire process.

Is this something that can be done by running blast from the command line and a batch script?

Comment: Yes this can be done. If you want to know how, you need to be more specific on what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You should get at least **one** result: the one that encodes for the original protein. The others, if any, would be pseudogenes, if I follow you.

Anyway, a bit of programming may help help, check out [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page). Bioperl or Bioruby should have similar features.
In particular you can [BLAST using Biopython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec108)

Answer (score 0):

You might find this link useful:

https://www.biostars.org/p/5403/

A similar question has been asked there, and some reasonable solutions have been posted.